# Python integration / regression testing framework

Tags: python, pytest, integration-testing, regression-testing

I'm just wondering whether there is any good framework for doing integration / regression tests in Python? I want to run all modules on large input data files (sensor measurements) to ensure that new changes in the code have not introduced any new defect (for every commit). Of course, I could implement such tests + reporting by myself in some pytest sub directory, but maybe there are some out of the box solutions?

Thanks!

Cheers,
Alexey

Comment: what about [fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently heard about the `pytest-regressions` plugin for `pytest`, which seems like a good fit for your use case.

The authors describe it as:

> a pytest plugin that helps to test datasets and objects by automatically
> serializing expected data on disk and later checking test results against it

PyCon presentation:
https://us.pycon.org/2020/schedule/presentation/110/

Github page:
https://github.com/ESSS/pytest-regressions